# Convert all non-JPG images to JPGs

Tags: command, conversion, images

What command can I use to convert all images in a folder which are not JPGs (PNG and BMP primarily) to JPG? I'd also like the conversion quality to be 100%. And I'd like the converted images to replace the originals.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked into the `convert` utility that comes with `ImageMagick`, for example?

Comment: Install [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) from your distro repo, and use the Command Line processor in [Batch Mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

Comment: @DopeGhoti Will this work? mogrify -format jpg *.png  How to also get it to convert BMPs to JPGs with the same command?

Comment: @user8547: no, it won't. You need to iterate over all filenames, you cant just supply them all to `mogrify`.

Comment: @Bananguin - apparently, `ImageMagick` devs [don't share](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) your opinion.

Comment: @don_crissti: but the man page shipped with Debian does. So this feature still needs to spread it seems ... or the man page is broken. Documentation is not valued as much as it used to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are only images in that folder, you can

```
ls | grep -v jpg$
```

to get all filenames that do not end with `jpg`, which I assume are all the images you want to convert. Then you can use the tool `convert` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) like this

```
ls | grep -v jpg$ | while IFS= read -r FILENAME
do
    convert "${FILENAME}" "${FILENAME%.*}.jpg"
done
```

The `convert` command expands to `convert <file name as printed by ls> <file name without extention>.jpg`. The extention `jpg` will tell `convert` to convert to jpg format.

Comment: Can the extension PNG and BMP replace "FILENAME"? I want the command to automatically find all non-JPG images in a folder of images. I don't want to have to manually add the path or the filename of the non-JPG images.

Comment: Replace jpg$ w/ png$ for pngs and bmp$  The `ls` command is the input buffer

Comment: @eyoung100 Like this: "ls | grep -v png$ bmp$ | while read FILENAME" ??

Comment: No, one at a time png's 1st then bmp's

Comment: @eyoung100 Is there a command I can use that will convert both PNG and BMP in the same command?

Comment: Not in this format, as the command on the left is the input and the output becomes the input to the last pipe, and FILENAME is a shell built-in, It only reads one filename at a time, and AFAIK, you can't read in more than 1.

Comment: @user8547: if you are specifically looking to convert just all bmp and png images, you can use the while loop provided above, but replace `ls | grep -v jpg$` with `echo *.{bmp,png}`. Within that `echo` statement, you can even complement the ,-separated list of extentions to include other formats as well.

Comment: @Bananguin So the final command would look like this: "echo *.{bmp,png} | while read FILENAME
do
    convert ${FILENAME} ${FILENAME%.*}.jpg
done"

Comment: @user8547: no, you forgot the * before the . and a ; after FILENAME and another ; after jpg. The newlines matter. Maybe your shell's manual can help you with these details ...

Comment: @Bananguin So the command should look like this: http://i.imgur.com/J8EMwwV.png

Comment: @Bananguin Tx, I got it working, but it doesn't overwrite the original files, which I would like it to do.

Comment: More robust: `for x in *; do case $x in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg]) :;; *) convert -- "$x" "${x%.*}.jpg";; esac; done`

Comment: @Gilles Tx Gilles! That one works as well. Can you modify it so that the original non-JPG files are overwritten with the converted JPGs?

Comment: @user8547: yes, that should work. I don't think convert will modify in place, but you can add a line right after the `convert` line `rm ${FILENAME}`, which will delete the original file.

Answer (score 4):

To convert all `.png` and `.bmp` in the current directory and then remove the original files:

```
mogrify -format jpg -quality 100 ./*.{png,bmp}
rm ./*.{png,bmp}
```

To convert all files except `.jpg`, if your shell supports extended globbing, e.g. `bash`:

```
shopt extglob
mogrify -format jpg -quality 100 ./*.!(jpg)
rm ./*.!(jpg)
```

or `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
mogrify -format jpg -quality 100 ./^*.jpg
rm ./^*.jpg
```

Recursive:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.jpg' -exec \
mogrify -format jpg -quality 100 {} + -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a further solution using the XNView CLI program [nConvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/). [Here's an installation tutorial](https://pastebin.com/zMAHqaWY) for nConvert for Linux.

The following nConvert command will convert any image formats to jpg, and the rm command will delete all bmp and png files:

```
nconvert -out jpeg -o output-##.jpg *.* && rm ./*.{png,bmp}
```